# SQL Display results only if the row exists in another table

Tags: sql

Is there a way to display results only if that particular value exists, if there are multiple entries of it in another table?

For example, I am trying to display teacher name only if the type is Math. If there are no entries of Math, the column Teacher should display none.

| UserName U | Email |
| --- | --- |
| Me | row@1.com |
| Wiz | bow@1.com |

| Classes C | Username |
| --- | --- |
| First | Me |
| Second | Me |
| Third | Me |
| Third | Wiz |

| Classes | Teacher T | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | Math |
| Second | B | Math |
| Third | C | NULL |

Final result as Math Classes exist for Me

| UserName | Email | Teacher |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Me | row@1.com | A |
| Me | row@1.com | B |

Final result as Math Classes exist for Wiz with no math classes

| UserName | Email | Teacher |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wiz | bow@1.com | None |

The issue I'm running into is that my query is displaying either no entries even though user has no math but has other classes, or it's displaying Math and None at the same time.

My current query is as follows:

```
from User u
join classes c on c.username=u.username
join teachers t on t.classes=c.classes and type ='Math' <---- If I left join, I get 2 entries, if I join, I get 0 entries for non-math folks
where username ='Me'
```

So the 3 scenarios I want the query to cover:

1. If user does not exist in the user table (no entry)
2. If user exists but doesn't have any math (show user None entry)
3. If user exists and has math (regardless of any other type) display classes - final situation up there

Do I do some kind of select count in the case statement? This query is part of a bigger execution query.

This was SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: It's not clear what the table names or related columns are in your sample data

Comment: your query has `where username ='' `, but no row in your example data matches that value...  Same is value for `type = 2`.

Comment: It seems like you tried to simplify your tables, which is generally awesome, but now the example query doesn't match up right (as Luuk and Stu mentioned above).  Could you either add the missing columns (`type`, `id`, `userid` to your tables, or simplify the query to match the tables shown?  Would be good to include an example of each condition in the sample data too, I can't quite tell if you did or not since the query doesn't match up.

Comment: Hope these edits make more sense, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this solve your question?

```
select u.Username, 
       Email, 
       CASE WHEN types = 'MATH'
       THEN teacher
       ELSE 'None'
       end as teacher
from users u
join class c on c.username=u.username
join teacher t on t.classes=c.classes
WHERE u.Username = 'Wiz'
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=131cc808b0d086d6a27c9d1a7431f684)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the username is changed to "Me". None as a value shows up as row result. If there are math classes, none shouldn't show up even if the teacher teaches other non-math classes, but if there are no math classes, then none should show up